# Work with direct acces binary file

Tags: c

I'm new at C (programming at all actually), and I need to do a tic tac toe game for college.

At the end of each game I need to save the players information on a txt file and the game information in a binary file.

The .txt is as following :
playerName;X|O;playerName;X|O

The binarye file receives the match number, the whole array (3x3) with the players turns (X|O) and the match result (X|O|V <-for a draw).

As I need to show all matches at the end of a battery of games, I'm intendig to iterate through the txt file and for each line, access the correpondent information at the binary files.

This correctly generate the txt file:

```
void inc_txt(){
FILE *f = fopen("tictac.txt", "a+");
fprintf (f, "%s;%c;%s;%c\n", name1, jog1, name2, jog2);
fclose(f);
}
```

This apparently records just one occurency of match details:

```
void inc_bin(char result){
memcpy(Match.TicTac, tictac, sizeof(Match.TicTac));
Match.result = result;
FILE *bfp = fopen ("tictac.bin", "wb"); 
fwrite(&Match, sizeof(struct TicTac), 1, bfp);
fclose(bfp);    
}
```

This succesfully prints out the contents of one match from the bin file:

```
FILE* f1 = fopen ("tictac.bin", "rb");
fread(&Match, 1, sizeof(struct TicTac), f1);
printf("Match: %d \n", Match.match);
for(int lin = 0 ; lin < 3 ; lin++){
    for(int col = 0 ; col < 3 ; col++){
        printf(" %c ", Match.TicTac[lin][col]);
        if(col != (3-1))
          printf("|");
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
putchar('\n');
printf("Result: %c", Match.result);
fclose(f1);
```

In pascal (studying alg) I used to declare a type and then a file of that type, then seek(file, position) and could read or write at the given position(that I would get by iterating the txt file), with no problems, but I couldn't realize how to achieve equivalent task in C. Feel that I should multiply the block size or fread pointer somehow, but couldn't find a solution so far.

How could I find specif match details from the binary file?

Comment: If you already know how to generate the .txt file, to write to the bin file and read from the files... what do you want to know exactly?

Comment: The C equivalent to the Pascal function you mention is `fseek()`, usually used on a structured binary file, not a text file. Also, your code that successfully prints one match result, if you call the similar `fread` again, you get the *next* match result in the file.

Comment: So I must use fseek() on write at th bin file.
fseek(bfp, linefromcounttxt, seek_set)?
My misunderstanding of the seek is that in pascal I declare the file as "file of structure", but hadn't found anything similar on C. How do I specify the block lenght?
Also, no need to seek on read since I'll be iterating the txt file, right?

Comment: int size = (Match.match-1)*sizeof(Match);
    fseek(bfp, size, SEEK_SET);

That did the trick of fseeking, also, I was opening the file with "wb" and that was bogusing the file, "ab" solved the matter.

Thank you

Comment: But calling fread multiple times gets the same match over and over again, as in Pascal, needed to seek on fread too.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new at C (programming at all actually), and I need to do a tic tac toe game for college.

These three do not compute! One should not be generally new to programming and new to C at the same time, as the only reasonable guides seem to assume a minimum prerequisite knowledge.

Sure, you'll find those who claim to teach C as an introductory language. I'm not saying it's not possible to learn C as a first language through your college, but I wouldn't be confident enough to bet on it. A good book, however, will get you there.

Perhaps SICP, prior to K&R2E would be good. It seems like you could use some guidance in using arguments more liberally; SICP will help you with that.

Moving on...

---

> In pascal ...

I would no sooner learn C as though it has similarities with Pascal than I would learn French as though it has similarities with German. They're both procedural programming languages, and there are some other vague similarities on the surface with some shocking yet subtle gotchas woven betwixt. You should learn languages that have UB as though they might have a secret door with a gas or spike trap... all in the fun of exploration, of course!

---

> ... I used to declare a type and then a file of that type, then seek(file, position) and could read or write at the given position(that I would get by iterating the txt file), with no problems, but I couldn't realize how to achieve equivalent task in C.

As the idea of *files* came from Unix, and C is recognised as the Unix system language, the idea is very similar in C. You can use `fseek` to `fseek(file, index * size_of_object, SEEK_SET)`, for example. Or, if you're bound to a particularly Unix-like system (such as Linux, BSD, Solaris, Mac OS, etc) you could use `mmap` to map a region of memory to a file, so you could for example, treat a 2GB file as though it's your array. You've got a few manuals to read before that's an option, but it's a good option to look into.

---

> How could I find specif match details from the binary file?

1. Read an item from the file.
2. Test the item to check if it's the one you're looking for. If not, go to 1.
3. If necessary, re-read the item and/or perform a final test to ensure the item you've read is a match.

---

P.S. I would expect (and thus suggest) the `size` argument to be `sizeof (struct TicTac)`, and the `nitems` argument to be `1`, not the other way around... The other way around is more likely buggy. Look at how you've written your `fwrite` code as a good example: `fwrite(&Match, sizeof(struct TicTac), 1, bfp);`... now replace `fwrite` with `fread` and you have a read instead of a write. However, in your reads, you swap the middle arguments which changes the behaviour slightly.